# How to show that a language is not regular using the Myhill-Nerode Theorem?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

I need to show that the language below  is not regular using the Myhill-Nerode Theorem, and I am currently a bit lost, how would I do that with this theorem?

```
Σ={a,b,c}

and

ADD={a^i b^j c^k ∣ i>=2 and GCD(j,k)=/=1}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Well I don't know the Myhill-Nerode Theorem, nor even what a regular language is, but surely the answer to your question is clear, at least in the abstract. If you're given that the theorem is supposed to be relevant the theorem must be of the form "If $L$ is a regular language then [_something_]"; you'd use that to show $L$ is not regular by showing that [_something_] does not hold here. (If you understood that and were wondering how to show that [_something_] fails my apologies; we _do_ get questions here from people who can't get that far themselves...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Myhill-Nerode theorem, language $L$ is regular if and only if the number of equivalence classes of relation $R_L$, defined as $xR_L y \iff \{z\in T^*:xz \in L\}=\{z\in T^*:yz \in L\}$, where $T^*$ is the set of all words in given alphabet, is finite. If you take two words from $L$, $w_1=a^{i_1} b^p c^{k_1}$ and $w_2=a^{i_2} b^p c^{k_2}$, where $k_1 \neq k_2$ and $p$ is prime, $w_1c^m \in L \land w_2c^m \in L \iff \mathrm{GCD}(p,k_1+m) \neq 1 \land \mathrm{GCD}(p,k_2+m) \neq 1$. But $\mathrm{GCD}(p,k_1) \neq 1 \land \mathrm{GCD}(p,k_2) \neq 1$, which means $k_1$ and $k_2$ are equal $n_1p$ and $n_2p$, $n_1,n_2\geqslant2$, so $m$ must be proportional to $p$, too. Hence, $[a^2 b^p c^{2p}]=\{a^m b^p c^{np}:n\geqslant2, m\geqslant2\}$ and we found an infinite set of equivalence classes, because they are different for each prime $p$.